# Slow String Formatting in C# when using more than a few lines

Tags: c#, string, parsing, templates

I have created a process which reads a "template" text file and then based on the String.Format requirements uses the tokens to place my custom text in.

So, everything works, but the process is slow.

The template file can have about 500-1000 lines; I am looking for a way to speed this process up.

Any ideas?

Here is my code below:

```
templateFilePath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase).Replace("file:\\", "");
templateFilePath += "\\Templates\\TemplateFile.txt";
tempRequestFilePath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
tempRequestFilePath += Guid.NewGuid();
Directory.CreateDirectory(tempRequestFilePath);
responseFileToWrite = tempRequestFilePath + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(zipMergeFilePath) + ".RSP";
if (!File.Exists(templateFilePath))
{
    return false;
}
templateString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(templateFilePath);
currentRecordNumber = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < createToProcess.rtfText.Lines.Length; i++)
{
    if (createToProcess.rtfText.Lines[i].Contains("TAG ID:"))
    {
        string currentTagID = createToProcess.rtfText.Lines[i].Substring(9, 11).Trim();
        string currentCustomerNumber = createToProcess.rtfText.Lines[i].Substring(25, 12).Trim();
        string currentTaxPeriod = createToProcess.rtfText.Lines[i].Substring(42, 8).Trim();
        string currentCustomerPhoneNumber = createToProcess.rtfText.Lines[i].Substring(55, 9).Trim();
        DateTime datePurchases = (DateTime.Now).AddDays(-7);
        DateTime dateReceived = (DateTime.Now).AddYears(10);
        DateTime dateModified = (DateTime.Now).AddYears(-1);
        string currentResearchCreateRecord = String.Format(templateString,
            currentTagID.PadRight(6),
            currentCustomerNumber.PadRight(12),
            currentTaxPeriod.PadRight(6),
            currentCustomerPhoneNumber.PadRight(8),
            datePurchases.Month.ToString("00") + datePurchases.Day.ToString("00") + datePurchases.Year.ToString("0000"),
            "RecordNo: " + currentRecordNumber.ToString(),
            dateReceived.Month.ToString("00") + dateReceived.Day.ToString("00") + dateReceived.Year.ToString("0000"),
            dateModified.Month.ToString("00") + dateModified.Day.ToString("00") + dateModified.Year.ToString("0000")
            );
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
        File.AppendAllText(responseFileToWrite, currentResearchCreateRecord);
        currentRecordNumber += 1;
    }
}
using (ZipFile currentZipFile = new ZipFile())
{
    currentZipFile.AddFile(responseFileToWrite, "");
    currentZipFile.Save(zipMergeFilePath);
}
return true;
```

Comment: `createToProcess.rtfText.Lines` sure is getting called a lot.  Is that breaking a string into lines every time you call it?

Comment: You are right; I will place in a temp array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're re-opening the file handle for each line.  That's an expensive operation, and slows you down.

Instead, create (in a `using` block) a `StreamWriter` for the file, and call `WriteLine()` to write a single line without closing the file.

---

Also, reading the `Lines` property is [quite slow](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBoxBase.cs,37cabfde1449b18f).  Change that to a `foreach` loop (or just cache the array) instead of rerunning all that code for each line.

Finally, don't call `DoEvents()`.

Comment: Thanks for this info; I will try it right away and then mark as an answer if all goes well. Quick question though on the `StreamWriter.WriteLine()` part; as you will note in the above example I pull the entire template text and then that _entire_ template text get's written each time. Would `StreamWriter.WriteLine()` work for multiple lines to text to write in this instance?

Comment: To answer my own question, `StreamWriter.WriteLine()` does write multiple lines.

Comment: @ChrisK.: Yes; `Line` just means that it adds a newline.

Answer (score 0):

be careful with "+" operator, they are very slow.

You should to use "StringBuilder" operator

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder((int)(sLen * Loops * 1.1));
for(i=0;i<Loops;i++) sb.Append(sSource);
sDest = sb.ToString();
```

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306822